# Convert a list from findall predicate to a string prolog

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I am struggling to identify a way to convert a list to string. This list is the output from a findall predicate.

see below my code.

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,c).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,d).
edge(c,e).
edge(d,e).
edge(f,g).
edge(g,h).

route(X, Z, [])    :-  edge(X, Z).
route(X, Z, [Y|T]) :-  edge(X, Y), route(Y, Z, T).

allways(X, Y) :- findall(E, (route(X, Y, E), write(E), nl), _).
%allways(X, Y) :- findall(E, (route(X, Y, E), with_output_to(atom(_),maplist(write, E)), nl), _).
%allways(X, Y) :- findall(E, (route(X, Y, E), atomic_list_concat(E,'',A), nl), _),write(A).
```

my output

```
?- allways(a,e).
[b,c]
[b,c,d]
[c]
[c,d]
```

expected output

```
?- allways(a,e).
bc
bcd
c
cd
```

I tried different ways to convert the list to string using with_output_to predicate and atomic_list_concat predicate but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "string", what do you mean?

There are many predicates for concatenating a list to an atom. In your case `atomic_list_concat/2` sounds about right.

Your problem however is in how you wrote the findall, you are capturing the wrong variable.

```
?- findall(Str, ( route(a, e, E), atomic_list_concat(E, Str) ), Strs),
   forall(member(Str, Strs), format("~w~n", [Str])).
```

or, if you do not need the list at all, do not use findall at all.

```
?- forall(( route(a, e, E),
            atomic_list_concat(E, Str)
          ),
          format("~w~n", [Str])).
```

Comment: your understanding of the string seem is ok (without the comma) to me. But i wanted to output 'Str' rather than the 'Strs' from your code. I modified your suggestion but it is not working. ``` findall(E, (route(X, Y, E), atomic_list_concat(E,write(Str))), Strs) ```

Comment: @mkpisk The `write` should **not** be inside the findall, this is for certain. Take my code exactly as is, and _after_ the findall do the writing. And do not put code in comments.

Comment: It is not working if I write(Str) outside by giving a , (AND condition) to findall.

Comment: @mkpisk there are (countably?) infinite ways to make something that is not working. See my edited answer.

Comment: awesome. It is a new trick to use forall and the way you wrote format. Thank you very much for teaching :)